# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable in merge sort

Tags: mergesort

I am trying to write merge sort algorthim in python. I am keeping this error TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

```
def merge(c,b,m,e):

    i = b,j = m+1
    l=[]
    while (i<=m) and (j<=e):
        if (c[i] < c[j]):
            l.append(c[i])
        else:
            l.append(c[j])
    if (i<=m):
        while (i<=m):
            l.append(c[i])
    else:
        while(j<=e):
            l.append(c[j])

    for i1 in l:
        print(l[i1])

def merge_sort(collection,beg,end):


    if(beg<end):
        mid=(beg+end)//2
        merge_sort(collection,beg,mid)
        merge_sort(collection,mid+1,end)
        merge(collection,beg,mid,end)
        #return collection



if __name__ == '__main__':


    user_input = input('Enter numbers separated by a comma:\n').strip()

    unsorted = [int(i) for i in user_input.split(',')]
    l = len (unsorted)

    merge_sort(unsorted,0,l)
```

Comment: What's the full error with trace?

Comment: This also looks like it will result in infinite loops. Your while loops depend on the values of i and e, yet you never alter either.

Comment: The more I look over this code, the more problems I see. You should really write and test small pieces at a time instead of throwing down a bunch of code then trying to fix it all at once afterwards.

Comment: sorry I forgot to increment the value of i and j.

Comment: The following is the error -  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\mergesort.py", line 68, in <module>
    merge_sort(unsorted,0,l)
  File "C:\Users\Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\mergesort.py", line 29, in merge_sort
    merge_sort(collection,beg,mid)
  File "C:\Users\Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\mergesort.py", line 29, in merge_sort
    merge_sort(collection,beg,mid)  File "C:\Users\Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\mergesort.py", line 31, in merge_sort

Comment: merge_sort(collection,beg,mid)
  File "C:\Users\Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\mergesort.py", line 31, in merge_sort
    merge(collection,beg,mid,end)
  File "C:\Users\Dey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\mergesort.py", line 4, in merge
    i = b,j = m+1
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable